# How to get max and min value in array of objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, data-structures, reduce

I need to get the maximum and minimum value of an array with several objects. I know that in Javascript we can use `Math.min` and `Math.max` for this, in addition to other strategies.

This solution of mine is working, but I'm finding the code too verbose. Can you tell me how to improve it?

Thank you very much in advance.

Here's my code I put into [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-bush-bly7rw?file=/src/App.js)

```js
const skuStylePlu = [{
    skuPrice: {
      currentPrice: {
        amount: 10
      }
    }
  },
  {
    skuPrice: {
      currentPrice: {
        amount: 20
      }
    }
  },
  {
    skuPrice: {
      currentPrice: {
        amount: 30
      }
    }
  },
  {
    skuPrice: {
      currentPrice: {
        amount: 40
      }
    }
  },
  {
    skuPrice: {
      currentPrice: {
        amount: 50
      }
    }
  }
];

let lowest = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
let highest = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
let temp;

for (let i = skuStylePlu.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  temp = skuStylePlu[i].skuPrice.currentPrice;

  if (temp.amount < lowest) {
    lowest = temp.amount;
  }
  if (temp.amount > highest) {
    highest = temp.amount;
  }
}

console.log(lowest, highest); // return 10, 50
```

Comment: Your code is fine if you don't want to use those two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the reduce method instead of a for loop.

```js
const skuStylePlu = [{
    skuPrice: {
      currentPrice: {
        amount: 10
      }
    }
  },
  {
    skuPrice: {
      currentPrice: {
        amount: 20
      }
    }
  },
  {
    skuPrice: {
      currentPrice: {
        amount: 30
      }
    }
  },
  {
    skuPrice: {
      currentPrice: {
        amount: 40
      }
    }
  },
  {
    skuPrice: {
      currentPrice: {
        amount: 50
      }
    }
  }
];
const prices = skuStylePlu.map(obj => obj.skuPrice.currentPrice.amount);
const lowest = prices.reduce((acc, curr) => Math.min(acc, curr), Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
const highest = prices.reduce((acc, curr) => Math.max(acc, curr), Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY);
console.log(lowest, highest);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Rory!! That's great

Answer (score 1):

You could start with the value at index zero and get the value directly, bnot the last object.

Then loop until index one.

```js
const
    skuStylePlu = [{ skuPrice: { currentPrice: { amount: 10 } } }, { skuPrice: { currentPrice: { amount: 20 } } }, { skuPrice: { currentPrice: { amount: 30 } } }, { skuPrice: { currentPrice: { amount: 40 } } }, { skuPrice: { currentPrice: { amount: 50 } } } ];
    
let lowest = skuStylePlu[0].skuPrice.currentPrice.amount,
    highest = skuStylePlu[0].skuPrice.currentPrice.amount,
    i = skuStylePlu.length;

while (--i) {
    const value = skuStylePlu[i].skuPrice.currentPrice.amount;
    if (value < lowest) lowest = value;
    if (value > highest) highest = value;
}

console.log(lowest, highest); // return 10, 50
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use object destructuring to tidy things a little.

With a for of loop:

```js
const skuStylePlu = [{"skuPrice":{"currentPrice":{"amount":10}}},{"skuPrice":{"currentPrice":{"amount":20}}},{"skuPrice":{"currentPrice":{"amount":30}}},{"skuPrice":{"currentPrice":{"amount":40}}},{"skuPrice":{"currentPrice":{"amount":50}}}];

let lowest = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
let highest = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;

for(const { skuPrice: { currentPrice: { amount } } } of skuStylePlu) {
  lowest = lowest < amount ? lowest : amount;
  highest = highest > amount ? highest : amount;
}

console.log(lowest, highest);
```

Single reduce for slightly increased terseness:

```js
const skuStylePlu = [{"skuPrice":{"currentPrice":{"amount":10}}},{"skuPrice":{"currentPrice":{"amount":20}}},{"skuPrice":{"currentPrice":{"amount":30}}},{"skuPrice":{"currentPrice":{"amount":40}}},{"skuPrice":{"currentPrice":{"amount":50}}}];

const [lowest, highest] = skuStylePlu.reduce(
  ([low, high], { skuPrice: { currentPrice: { amount } } }) =>
    [ low < amount ? low : amount, high > amount ? high : amount ],
  [Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY]
);

console.log(lowest, highest);
```